# How do I pass a list as a parameter in a user-defined function?

Tags: python-3.x

How do I pass a list as a parameter in a function?

I am trying to form a user-defined function called 'get_all_latitude' where it will extract the latitude according to its listing id from a dataset. An excerpt of the dataset (it is a list of dictionaries) is as follows:

```
{
    'listing_id': '1133718',
    'survey_id': '1280',
    'host_id': '6219420',
    'room_type': 'Shared room',
    'country': '',
    'city': 'Singapore',
    'borough': '',
    'neighborhood': 'MK03',
    'reviews': 9.0,
    'overall_satisfaction': 4.5,
    'accommodates': '12',
    'bedrooms': '1.0',
    'bathrooms': '',
    'price': 74.0,
    'minstay': '',
    'last_modified': '2017-05-17 09:10:25.431659',
    'latitude': 1.293354,
    'longitude': 103.769226,
    'location': '0101000020E6100000E84EB0FF3AF159409C69C2F693B1F43F'
}
```

This is my progress thus far:

```
def get_all_latitude(data, list_id):
    new_list = []
    for row in data:
         if row['listing_id'] == list_id:
                new_list.append(row['latitude'])
                return new_list
```

This works if I only have 1 listing id as the 2nd argument (e.g. `get_all_latitude(airbnb_data, '1133718'`) but I am wondering how I can get it to work with a list (e.g. `get_all_latitude(airbnb_data, ['10350448','13507262','13642646'])` ) as I do not know how to code it in a way where it will unpack the elements of a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
def get_all_latitude(data, list_id):
    new_list = []
    for row in data:
        if row['listing_id'] in list_id:
            new_list.append(row['latitude'])
            return new_list
```

Or if you want to define list for all list id:

```
def get_all_latitude(data, list_ids):
    new_lists = {list_id:list() for list_id in list_ids}
    for row in data:
         if row['listing_id'] == list_id:
            new_list[row['listing_id']].append(row['latitude'])
    return new_lists
```